# how can I embed power bi in my android App?

Tags: android, powerbi-embedded

I would like to embed power bi in my android application.

So through Rest API I got embedURL and embedToken. How should we proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which framework you are using for your android app. if you are using a js based framework you can simply use the pbi js library:

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript

You should also read about embedding in mobile layouts with this powerbi-client JS library:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile

Otherwise, you should find a way to encapsulate js code inside your app.